# How can I use an importmap when some of the js files don't include a valid relative reference symbol(s)?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, vtk.js

I'm loading `vtk.js` from unpkg in a simple `index.html` file like so:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/polyfill@7.0.0/dist/polyfill.js"></script>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "vtk/": "https://unpkg.com/vtk.js/"
        }
    }
  </script>
  <script type="module">
   import 'vtk/Sources/favicon';
   import 'vtk/Sources/Rendering/Profiles/Geometry';
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I load this in the browser I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/OpenGL/Profiles/Geometry". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

`vtk/Sources/favicon` imports without issue, but `vtk/Sources/Rendering/Profiles/Geometry` fails.

When I look at the [vtk.js source](https://github.com/Kitware/vtk-js/blob/master/Sources/Rendering/Profiles/Geometry.js) I can see the problem, `Geometry` isn't actually doing anything other than importing two other modules and it doesn't have an appropriate relative reference before it.

```js
import 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/OpenGL/Profiles/Geometry';
import 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/WebGPU/Profiles/Geometry';
```

Since these files are not under my control I can't modify them to have the relative url prefix. Is there another option?

Note: I know I really should be actually bundling the package with my app, even [vtk.js docs say so](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/docs/intro_vtk_as_external_script.html) but they also seem to indicate that using unpkg is possible and may be useful for fast prototyping.

At this point I'll just install the package so I don't waste more time on it...but I'm still curious how I could get this working with the hosted vtk.js (or if it isn't possible)?

Thanks!